# check duplication of cookies in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am writing automated test scripts to check the duplication of cookies in Ruby. I am using the following code to obtain the value of a particular cookie.

```
browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
   cookie  = browser.manage.cookie_named("__utma")
        if cookie[:value].eql? $tracking_parameter
     else
       puts cookie[:value]
     exit
   end
```

I would like to know if the cookie __utma is present twice or duplicated, then how the code can be changed in order to test?

Comment: Aren't cookies sent and parsed as a serialized object, making this test impossible to fail anyway?

Comment: No there are not. I would like to find a way to process the cookie with out involving serialization.

Comment: Err… The cookies are sent and stored as text, so they're necessarily serialized somehow (as JSON, in all likelihood)… Whether you can read them as objects or not depends on whether your app has unserialized them accordingly prior to exposing them using an API.